# (bash scripting) Is there a way to get the actual errno of a failed attempt to write to a file?

Tags: bash, locking, errno

Which is to say:

```
$ cp /usr/cat c
$ ./c
```

(different window)

```
$ echo foo > c
-bash: c: Text file busy
$ echo $?
1
```

Technically, internally the actual write returned -ETXTBSY (-26).  Is there a way to get that code instead of 1 with regular bash tools?  Short of parsing the text or writing a short C program (this is in a weirdly controlled environment).

Comment: I think it's rather `ETXTBSY 26 Text file busy`

Comment: Fair enough, but the main goal is to get that code out be it -16 or -26.

Comment: Succinctly, no.  You'd probably have to capture the output (probably written to `stderr`, not `stdout` — but programs aren't all as disciplined as they should be) and then analyze the error message string to deduce the error number.  Decidedly non-trivial.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get that code

You can write a builtin module that prints errno.

The following source code saved as `geterrno.c`:

```
#include <config.h>
#if defined (HAVE_UNISTD_H)
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "posixstat.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "posixtime.h"
#include "bashansi.h"
#include "shell.h"
#include "builtins.h"
#include "common.h"
#include "bashgetopt.h"

static int geterrno_builtin(WORD_LIST *list) {
    printf("%d\n", errno);
    return (EXECUTION_SUCCESS);
}

static char *doc[] = {
    "geterrno: prints errno",
    NULL
};

struct builtin geterrno_struct = {
    "geterrno",
    geterrno_builtin,
    BUILTIN_ENABLED,
    doc,
    "getrrno: prints errno",
    0,
};
```

compiled and loaded with:

```
$ gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSHELL -I/usr/include/bash -I/usr/include/bash/include -I/usr/include/bash/builtins -I/usr/lib/bash -fPIC -shared -o libgeterrno.so
$ enable -f ./libgeterrno.so geterrno
```

After that, you can potentially with a lot of luck:

```
$ geterrno ; echo a > c ; geterrno
0
bash: c: Text file busy
26
```

> with regular bash tools?

No, that is impossible.